# wxPython using wxTimer : my box doesn't move

Tags: timer, wxpython

I would like to animate a blue box inside a panel, using a wxTimer. But nothing happens

- I set up a custom panel class in which i draw the box
- I set up a custom frame, which integrates my custom panel

Here my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

import wx

WHITE_COLOR = (255,255,255)

class AnimationPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.boxParameters = [10,10,60,60]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*WHITE_COLOR))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        timer = wx.Timer(self)
        timer.Start(100)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, timer)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.paintBox(dc)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.boxParameters[0] += 3
        self.Update()

    def paintBox(self, dc):
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("blue"))
        dc.DrawRectangle(*self.boxParameters)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Box with far and back movement", size=(300,200))
        AnimationPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a couple of things. First is that the wx.Timer is going out of scope once you've reached the end of the **init** method, so it's destroyed before it even gets to do anything. Next, you want to use Refresh() instead of Update() as Refresh() will mark the rectangle (or the entire screen) as "dirty" and cause it to be repainted. See the docs for more info: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html

Here's an updated version that works on my Windows box:

```
import wx

WHITE_COLOR = (255,255,255)

class AnimationPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.boxParameters = [10,10,60,60]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(*WHITE_COLOR))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)            
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.paintBox(dc)

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.boxParameters[0] += 3
        print self.boxParameters
        self.Refresh()

    def paintBox(self, dc):
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("blue"))
        dc.DrawRectangle(*self.boxParameters)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Box with far and back movement", size=(300,200))
        AnimationPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much : in fact I used the Update() method because I'm used to work with Java/Swing :S Thank you very much :)